# after push UIViewController app freeze swift

Tags: ios, swift, pushviewcontroller, hierarchical, eureka-forms

I use UITabBarController as the root controller, each TabBarItem has its own UINavigationController, the first UITabBar (0) refers to the UIViewController which displays the results from the server. The fifth UITabBar (4) includes the MoreFormViewController (it is the successor of the FormViewController from the Eureka framework) it has several cells (two are currently implemented). Clicking on one of them opens SettingsFormViewController (this is the successor from FormViewController from the Eureka framework), the first cell contains UISlider, which changes the settings for getting data from the server (which are displayed in UITabBar (0)). If this parameter changes, then when we return back to the MoreFormViewController, we automatically make the transition to UITabBar (0). If you quickly switch from UITabBar (0) again to the MoreFormViewController and open the SettingsFormViewController, the application is frozen. Found out the following that at this point SettingsFormViewController is initialized and all life cycle methods are triggered (viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear and so on). But the screen is not visible, then I looked at UI View hierarchical in Xcode, and it shows that the very first controller is SettingsFormViewController as it should be. All this time I checked on a real iPhone 7, then I decided to check on the simulator and iPhone 5, they did not find such a bug on it, everything works correctly. During the next test, when the application "froze" on the iPhone 7, I accidentally folded it and unfolded it and I saw this screen and it completely works. But if you repeat the same action, then again the application "freezes."

I was looking for information on this, but at the most I found that people simply "frozen" the application because they were pushing the controller out of the main thread. So I do not know what to do. Can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Also I tried to replace the SettingsFormViewController with a regular UIViewController with a slider, the result is the same. Removed everywhere isUserInteractionEnabled = false even in third-party frameworks to know exactly what is not the problem.